# Importing csv file with non english text return error on select data

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I have succesfully import CSV file with pgAdmin and getting error when select data:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 0: unexpected end of data

Also, I try to select data from terminal shell, getting same error.

In pgAdmin, on importing CSV file, file encoding set to UTF-8.

Imported file was saved in UTF-8, when I open them on notepad text is readable.

Database encoding set to UTF-8 from pg Admin.

At the terminal, `SET SERVER_ENCODING UTF-8; SHOW SERVER_ENCODING` returns me UTF-8;

This is my example of data, that I am trying to select:

Header:

```
client_id;date;status_name;arrive_date
```

Data:

```
-621;31.12.2020;Қайта ұшып кетті;07.01.2021
```

I think psql cant read text in Kazakh lanuage like this "Қайта ұшып кетті".

UPD: I am trying to select withot text in Kazakh language, works fine, but with Kazakh text, return error with encoding.

```
Clien_encoding - UTF8
Server_encoding - UTF8
```

I have delet records, change encoding, same error.

How to solve this trouble ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Please [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me my quation. I have change my quation, now I think it would be reabable fine and I get answer to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solving by changing column type from char to varchar. Now text select correctly